# Is the map function inefficient?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I'm learning a little bit of efficiency code.
I do the next code.
The map function returns a result slower.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVSBw.png

i'm doing something wrong?

```js
var user = [
    {
        name: 'Sebastian',
        age: 19
    },
    {
        name: 'Gabriela',
        age: 51
    },
    {
        name: 'Julian',
        age: 19
    }
]

console.time('map');
user.map(item => console.log(item.name));
console.timeEnd('map');
console.log('\n');
console.time('for');
for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
    console.log(user[i].name);
}
console.timeEnd('for');
```

Comment: Such naïve benchmarking should be taken with a grain of salt. It's too sensitive to other stuff going on in the computer at the time. Also note that the code isn't equivalent. `map` creates a new array, the `for` doesn't.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. *i'm doing something wrong ?* We don't know, you never stated any problem in your question.

Comment: `user.map(item => console.log(item.name));` *do not use `.map()` for simple iteration of arrays*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I add a image and the code for running. I didnt expect responses so much faster.

Comment: You should be comparing for with forEach and not map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, JavaScript is not a programming language where doing something in the cleanest way is also the most efficient way. C, D, and C++ are languages that are designed that way.

If you look into V8 internals, you'll notice that map has to deal with array holes, making it slower.

Answer (score -2):

No it is not inefficient. You are comparing `map` with normal `for`. `.map` adds a layer of abstraction from the outside scope with results in an increase in the execution time when compared with the normal `for`.

Comment: Time complexity doesn't mean what you think it means... It's irrelevant to this comparison.

Comment: The time complexity is `O(n)` in both cases, since it's a linear pass through the array. The complexity shows the *growth factor* of the function, not exact performance characteristics. It's possible to have an `O(1)` operation perform consistently worse than `O(n^2)`, since it tells you nothing about the running time.